# Playing sound in Ruby 1.9.2 on Windows 7?

Tags: ruby, windows, audio, winapi

When I follow [this tutorial](http://rubyonwindows.blogspot.com/2007/05/adding-sound-to-your-ruby-apps.html) on Ruby 1.9.2 on Win 7, I get this error:
[image]

Is there a simpler way to play a sound? (specifically, wav)

Comment: When such window is active, just press Ctrl+C, and it's text message will be copied in clipboard. And then you can google it – this dll problem is very popular.

Comment: P.S.: when I have such messages, I just search dll (for example, in another old ruby build, which has it) and copy it into ruby/bin.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're using Ruby 1.9.2 and the binary gem for win32-sound, the binary, has not been compiled or made compatible with Ruby 1.9.x, only Ruby 1.8

You can skip this using the RubyInstaller [DevKit](http://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit) downloadable from RubyInstaller website.

Please follow the instructions from the DevKit page to complete the installation. Also note that to install win32-sound, you will need to change the command for the gem installation.

First:

```
gem list win32
gem list windows
```

Uninstall all the win32- and windows gems

Then:

```
gem install win32-sound --platform=ruby
```

That should install and compile a binary compatible with your installed Ruby.

Hope that helps